# How to send file plus string to web api?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, asp.net-web-api

This shows how to capture form data, including a file, using web api: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2.

How is it done on the client side if you don't have a `<form>`? I need to send a file and a string to the web api app. This will come from a windows client. The user will click a button, I'll prepare the string, get the file and submit to the web api app.

How do I structure the call on the client when there is no `<form>`?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2996904/3110834).